# why is Xcode / clang translating my "-fno-objc-arc" to "-fno_objc_arc"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, clang

i have attempted to follow the advice at SF for turning off objective-C arc per file for one file by placing "-fno-objc-arc" next in the compilation flags for the file in the "Compile Sources" section of my build phases for my project.

this isn't working for me, in that ARC-related errors are still generated.

i see in the log for the file for which i attempted to do this the following warning:

"clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno_objc_arc'"

i notice that it shows underscores instead of dashes.  when i look at the generated compile line, it also shows underscores instead of dashes.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c
-arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0
-Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type
-Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function
-Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas
-Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof
-Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
-Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -mthumb "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))"
"-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)"
-miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -iquote /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/myproj-generated-files.hmap
-I/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/myproj-own-target-headers.hmap
-I/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/myproj-all-target-headers.hmap
-iquote /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/Voyeur.build/myproj-project-headers.hmap
-I/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
-I/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/DerivedSources/armv7
-I/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/DerivedSources
-F/x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -fno_objc_arc
-include /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-adnhewmpoabuzebrrqoplkebnugj/myproj-Prefix.pch
-MMD -MT dependencies -MF /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mySource.d
--serialize-diagnostics /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mySource.dia
-c /x/git/myproj/subdir/mySource.m
-o /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myproj.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mySource.o
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to answer my own question, the underscores were probably a remnant of having typed them in poorly at first, forgetting i had done this, but being stuck with them in the derived data cache.

the quick fix for this was to

1. close the project in Xcode
2. remove the folder /x/xcode/DerivedData/myproj-eqyvffptnyujnsgcmhlqunfmfytp
3. re-open the project in Xcode
4. re-build and re-run

in looking at the log generated after making these changes, the value there is appropriately "-fno-objc-arc", appearing later than "-fobjc-arc", and as per another stackoverflow.com answer, the last one on the command-line wins.

Comment: My derived data folder was at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-*

Comment: @BenFlynn, yes, that would be the default location.  i have taken it out of my home directory so that i can access it whether i'm logged in as one of a couple of different users on my mac.  hope i didn't confuse you or anyone else with that tidbit.

Comment: Not a problem at all. I spaced on where it was but a quick Google search settled it.

Comment: I had a similar error trying to integrate Cocos2D into an existing application and I needed to disable arc for included files. Using "-fno-objc-arc" instead of "fno-objc-arc" solved my problem.